# Excel's "Highlight Duplicate Cells" is highlighting values which are actually different

Tags: microsoft-excel

Simple test case:

- Create new workbook
- Format column A as "Text"
- Enter the following into cells A1 and A2:

> ```
> 1234567800000639
> 1234567800000630
> ```

- Select Column A, and in the "Conditional Formatting" submenu, select "Highlight Cells Rule" > "Duplicate Values".

Excel is highlighting these as duplicates, even though they are different.
[image: Screenshot of Excel]

I suspect Excel is treating them as numbers and it becomes a rounding error, but I have specifically set to Text format and visually see different values, so I'm not sure how to tell Excel to treat it as Text.

Comment: Excel handle the values as numbers and replace last four numbers with zeroes. This the reason of this problem.

Comment: It works in Google Sheets!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Excel has a 15-digit limit to numerical precision, and as you've worked out your numbers have 16 so Excel is converting to a number and can't tell they're not duplicates (despite the fact you've marked them as text and put `'` at the start of the numbers to signify a string).

One workaround is to concatenate a letter onto the column of strings you are testing for duplicates. As you can see here, by adding `"a"` on the front of your string Excel treats it as a real string.

[image]

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960322/find-duplicates-in-a-column-with-large-number-as-text

Comment: "despite ... signify a string" and still showing as a duplicate qualifies this as a bug IMO

Comment: Agreed! It's a bug that's been around for a while